# Finding the longest continuous series of events

Tags: r, time-series

I have time-series data for many different countries of overall more than 50 years. Now I want to find the longest recording period of data for each country. I have tried something but it does not work yet (When I checked the output, it returned not the correct number of continuous years for most of the cases and I don't know why):

```
cntry <- as.list(unique(df$country))
df$longest.ts <- NULL

for (i in cntry) {
    x <- max(diff(which(diff(df$year[df$country==i]) != 1)))
    df$longest.ts[df$country==i] <- x
}
```

I appreciate your help,
Best

Edit: my data.frame is very big and has a lot of different variables but essentially I have got something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    country = c("Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia",
"China","China","China","China","China","China","China","China"),
    year = c(1923,1924,1925,1940,1945,1946,1960,1961,1962,1963,1964,1965,1981,1982)
)
```

And I would like to get a output with the countries and the longest time-series within the country (e.g. here Bolivia: 3yrs, China: 6yrs).

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: Your `year` is a factor when it should be a numeric value. Convert to numeric using `as.numeric(as.character(year))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice trick using `diff` to take the differences and `rle` to encode the differences in pairs of `(value, times_repeated)` (run length encoding, see `?rle`).

For example, consider

```r
vec <- c(1960L, 1961L, 1962L, 1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 1981L, 1982L)
diff(vec)
#> [1]  1  1  1  1  1 16  1
rle(diff(vec))
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:3] 5 1 1
#>   values : int [1:3] 1 16 1
```

You want to find how many times in a row there is a difference of 1: this is the maximum length (+1) corresponding to a value of 1.

Putting that in a function (note the check on variable type, because in your example `year` is a factor instead of a numeric):

```
longest_ts <- function(vec) {
  if(!is.numeric(vec)) stop("Vector must be numeric!")
  RLE <- rle(diff(vec))
  max(RLE$lengths[RLE$values == 1]) + 1
}
```

Now just apply to your column (don't forget to `group_by`):

```
df <- data.frame(
  country = c("Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia","Bolivia",
              "China","China","China","China","China","China","China","China"),
  year = c("1923","1924","1925","1940","1945","1946","1960","1961","1962","1963","1964","1965","1981","1982")
)

library("dplyr")

df %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>%  # fix your year variable
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarise(longest_ts = longest_ts(year))
```

Result:

```
  country longest_ts
  <fct>        <dbl>
1 Bolivia          3
2 China            6
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It works perfectly fine like that. However, do you have an idea on how to deal with countries that show time-series for only one year? For now the function returns -Inf for 1yr data...